# How catch android.os.DeadObjectException

Tags: java, android, exception

I received a crash in crashlytic, which is caused by `android.os.DeadObjectException`. I googled this problem and found some answers, about that:

**The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists.**

I found answers about when this exception happened, if using a service, but my case is different.

Very hard to cause this exception, it's very random.

I use a bottom navigation bar with views (NO fragments) and this exception was caused through adding views. Here is the full stacktrace from crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:555)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:313)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:86)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2488)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
   at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:746)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:543)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:313)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:86)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2488)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

I think this is also caused by: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.`

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
    at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:148)
    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:759)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:531)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
    at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:425)
    at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.run(Toast.java:331)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How catch this exception?

Comment: where is your code in question?!

Comment: this is all my code